# Exporting custom Outlook formula field that includes a checkbox to Excel

Tags: excel, outlook-2010, vba

I am exporting Outlook emails in custom table view to Excel. There are custom formula fields in the custom view. All the custom fields export except the formula field.

This is the formula field:
'AssignedDate' formula field: IIf([RequestAssigned]=True,Now(),"")

'RequestAssigned' is a checkbox field, when checked AssignedDate field will capture the date and time when it is checked.

I get a run-time error message-

> Run-time error '-2147024809(8070057)':
>   could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid

If I remove that formula field the macro works.

```
Sub InboxToExcel()

    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objTable As Outlook.Table
    Dim objRow As Outlook.Row
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objRange As Excel.Range
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim strProps As String
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim intRow As Integer

    strProps = _
      "SenderName,To,Subject,SentOn,ReadReceiptRequested"
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objNS = objOL.Session
    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objTable = objInbox.GetTable

    Set objWB = GetExcelWB()
    Set objWS = objWB.Sheets(1)
    objWS.Name = "Inbox"
    arr = Split(strProps, ",")
    intRow = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        objWS.Cells(intRow, i + 1) = arr(i)
        objTable.Columns.Add arr(i)
    Next
    Set objRange = objWS.Range _
                   (objWS.Cells(1, 1), objWS.Cells(1, i + 1))
    objRange.Font.Bold = True
    Do Until objTable.EndOfTable 'POINTING HERE WHILE DEBUGGING
        intRow = intRow + 1
        Set objRow = objTable.GetNextRow
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            val = objRow(arr(i))

            objWS.Cells(intRow, i + 1) = val
        Next
    Loop
    For i = 1 To (UBound(arr) + 1)
        objWS.Columns(i).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next
    objWS.Application.Visible = True
    objWS.Activate
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objRow = Nothing
    Set objWB = Nothing
    Set objWS = Nothing
    Set objRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check the value of a checkbox directly in a formula.  The following link shows you how to set a surrogate cell to store the answer.

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/07/09/use-check-box-result-in-excel-formula/